# using randint to return random letter from string

Tags: python

so I have to make a function that takes one argument, a string 's' and it returns a random letter from the string 's', but it must make use of `randint(n, m)`.

like for an example:

if I pass it the string "hello!", it may return "h", or "e", or any other of the letters in "hello", but it should not return "m" or "n", since those letters are not in "hello!". Your function will return different things each time you pass it the same string, but (by chance) it may return the same answer multiple times in a row

here is what I have so far:

```
from random import randint

def random_element(s):
    #i'm really not sure what else to put after this since I am new to programming and I've never entirely used the "randint"
```

I don't understand what else to do, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The answer is in understanding "slicing".

Comment: Nevermind, a set's a bad idea for now. Instead, think about the "length" of the string, and each letter's "indexing".

Comment: Does it have to use randint or can it use another function from random? Such as choice

Comment: Lol @ *"here is what I have so far"* - so, nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a random number from 0 to the length of the string - 1, then access the character and return it:

```
from random import randint

def random_element(s):
    rand_index = randint(0, len(s)-1)
    return s[rand_index]
```

---

```
>>> random_element("hello")
'o'
>>> random_element("Stack Overflow")
'w'
>>> random_element("Stack Overflow")
'w'
>>> random_element("Stack Overflow")
'c'
>>> random_element("Stack Overflow")
'r'
>>> random_element("Stack Overflow")
'a'
>>> random_element("Stack Overflow")
'l'
>>>
```

Comment: It's not my downvote, but this seems like a case where handing out the answer on a platter hurts the OP more than it helps. That's why I left a hint in the comments rather than an answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom was about to argue then realized you were much more experienced than I :) Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Don't be intimidated by my score, I'm still quite capable of being wrong. Happens all the time, just ask my wife.

Comment: When the OP's question sounds suspiciously like a homework assignment, it's common practice to post a hint rather than an answer. I don't think you want to contribute to the proliferation of dumb developers.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want, I hope you get it:

```
def random_element(s):
    # s is a string
    # You can take its lenght and save it in a variable
    len_s = len(s)
    # And then return a random word like this, in the range l-1
    # because there is no index 5 since you start countint from 0, in other 
    # words  h e l l o
    #        0 1 2 3 4
    # and randint has a domain of a<=n<=b (the limits), where randint(a,b)
    # You get the word and then assign it to a variable
    letter = s[randint(0, len_s - 1)]
    return letter
```

Answer (score 0):

`randint` takes a start and end index and gives you a random number. Using `len` will give you the length of the string. This can be used for the end index and the start should always just be zero. String chars can be accessed using the [] notation.

All this together:

```
from random import randint
def random_element(s):
    random_number = randint(0, len(s)-1)
    return s[random_number]
```

Python docs can be easily found online.

I would also recommend `random.choice` for this.

Comment: This will return an IndexError if the random_number is `len(s)`.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the OP is required to use `random.randint()`, but for the sake of completeness... One should really use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) for choosing a random letter from a string (strings are sequences too)!

```
from random import choice

def random_element(s):
    return choice(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from random import randint

def random_element(s):
    return s[randint(0, len(s)-1)]

>>> print random_element('blah')
h
>>> print random_element('blah')
a
>>> print random_element('blah')
b
>>> print random_element('blah')
l
```

Comment: *"make the distribution of returned characters of the string `s` more uniform"* - not true. Seeding is useful for testing, where repeatability is required, but doesn't guarantee anything about the distribution of the outputs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But what if each call of ```randint``` uses the current system timestamp as seed i.e. a new seed for each call? Won't a fixed seed give a better possibility of picking indices uniformly?

Comment: That's... not how it works. You only seed the PRNG: 1. On first `import`; or 2. On explicit call to `seed`. What the seed happens to be doesn't affect the distribution, which over enough calls will always be uniformly distributed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, then it makes sense.